# Rails adding a backslash to symbols on a ruby command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphicsmagick

I am using this GraphicsMagick wrapper from https://github.com/dignoe/graphicsmagick

It works, but when I add any symbols, ruby adds a backslash which causes an error when running the command. How can I prevent this?

**Code:**

```
img.crop('360x504+432+72').resize('125x177!').write("public/#{path}/xs-" + filename)
```

**Produced Error Message:**

`GraphicsMagick::UnknownOptionError (gm mogrify -crop 360x504\+432\+72 -resize 125x177\! public//media/xs-cccc.JPG failed: gm mogrify: Option '-crop' requires an argument or argument is malformed.
):`

Comment: I don't think the backslash is the problem here (`^` usually needs to be escaped in shell commands). I'm looking at the [GraphicsMagick docs](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html) and it doesn't look like `^` is valid for the `-thumbnail` option. This is the valid format according to the docs: `-thumbnail <width>x<height>{%}{@}{!}{<}{>}`.

Comment: I got that part from the generating cropped thumbnail solution from here: http://superuser.com/questions/275476/square-thumbnails-with-imagemagick-convert

Comment: That question is about ImageMagick, not GraphicsMagick.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks, good catch. But this adding of backslash is an issue even when I put a `+` sign. I'll update my question. `GraphicsMagick::UnknownOptionError (gm mogrify -crop 360x504\+432\+72 -resize 125x177\! public//media/xs-cccc.JPG failed: gm mogrify: Option '-crop' requires an argument or argument is malformed.
):`

Comment: When I try `echo 360x504\+432\+72` it prints `360x504\+432\+7`. When I tried `gm mogrify -crop 360x504+432+72 -resize 125x177! public/media/xs-cccc.JPG`, it created the thumbnail without errors.

Comment: What happened when you did `gm mogrify -crop 360x504\+432\+72 -resize 125x177\! public//media/xs-cccc.JPG`? Also, what OS?

Comment: I tried without the backslashes and it worked. With slashes produces the error `gm mogrify: Option '-crop' requires an argument or argument is malformed.`. On Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably should have guessed at the outset that your problem is Windows. Windows is always fun.

Ruby's Shellwords module, which [the graphicsmagick gem uses](https://github.com/dignoe/graphicsmagick/blob/7c27eb72c3d0451f1e67bbc0af7b8eaecede02f8/lib/graphicsmagick/image.rb#L59), isn't designed to work with Windows ([per the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html), it "manipulates strings according to the word parsing rules of the UNIX Bourne shell"—there's a [long-standing issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8028) open for it).

Supposing I can't convince you to switch to an OS better suited to Ruby development, the best I can offer you is a hack. Use [`Module#prepend`](https://blog.ragnarson.com/2015/08/28/extending-objects-behavior-with-module-prepend.html) to change the behavior of `Shellwords.escape` to remove the backslashes from certain characters:

```
require "shellwords"

module UglyShellwordsHack
  def escape(*args)
    super.gsub(/\\([+^])/, '\1')
  end
end

Shellwords.singleton_class.prepend(UglyShellwordsHack)

puts Shellwords.escape("360x504+432+72")
# => 360x504+432+72
```

Of course, like all hacks, this is all but guaranteed to break at some point in the future.

P.S. You should probably mention in your [graphicsmagic issue](https://github.com/dignoe/graphicsmagick/issues/8) that you're using Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I Appreciate the time and efforts you put in to this issue. I've updated the issue.